# Pandas conditionally replace value if >1 unique values for other column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'A':['A','A','B','B','C','C'],
         'B':['Y','Y','N','N','Y','N'],
        })
df

    A   B
0   A   Y
1   A   Y
2   B   N
3   B   N
4   C   Y
5   C   N
```

I need a line of code that:
1. identifies if there are more than 1 unique values in column B for each category of A (i.e. category "C" in column A has 2 unique values in column B whereas categories "A" and "B" in column A only have 1 unique value each).
2. Changes the value in column B to "Y" **only if** there are more than 1 unique values per that category (i.e. Column B should have "Y" for both rows of category "C" in column A.

Here's the desired result:

```
    A   B

0   A   Y
1   A   Y
2   B   N
3   B   N
4   C   Y
5   C   Y
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Or, if column B contains both "Y" and "N" for a given category in column A, then change all values in column B for that category to "Y."

Comment: Sounds similar to 'more than 1 unique value'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

```
df['B'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x: 'Y' if x.nunique() > 1 else x)
```

to get:

```
   A  B
0  A  Y
1  A  Y
2  B  N
3  B  N
4  C  Y
5  C  Y
```

Comment: Nice use of conditional transform, more concise than mine. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'A':['A','A','B','B','C','C'],
         'B':['Y','Y','N','N','Y','N'],
        })

# Get unique items in each column A group
group_counts = df.groupby('A').B.apply(lambda x: len(x.unique()))
# Find all of them with more than 1 unique value
cols_to_impute = group_counts[group_counts > 1].index.values
# Change column B to 'Y' for such columns
df.loc[df.A.isin(cols_to_impute),'B'] = 'Y'

In [20]: df
Out[20]:
   A  B
0  A  Y
1  A  Y
2  B  N
3  B  N
4  C  Y
5  C  Y
```